# $2 \rightarrow 4$ process cross-section

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0307369) it appears that in the cross-section of the DDVCS process ($e^-(k)N(p_1)\rightarrow e^-(k^\prime)N(p_2)\ell(\ell_-)\bar{\ell}(\ell_+)$), the usual Lorentz-invariant phase-space ($d^4{\rm LIPS}$) can be factorized as follows

$$
d^4{\rm LIPS} = dM_{{\ell\bar{\ell}}}^2\ d^3{\rm LIPS}\ d\Phi_{\ell\bar{\ell}}
$$

I'm interested in $d^3{\rm LIPS}$. I want to prove how to go from eq. (4) to (6) in the paper, i.e., how to go from

$$
d^3{\rm LIPS} = (2\pi)^4 \delta(p_1 + k - p_2 - k^\prime - q_2)\frac{d^4 p_2}{(2\pi)^3}\delta_+(p_2^2 - M_N^2) \frac{d^4 k^\prime}{(2\pi)^3}\delta_+(k^{\prime\ 2})\frac{d^4 q_2}{(2\pi)^3}\times\\\delta_+(q_2^2 - M_{\ell\bar{\ell}}^2)
$$

to

$$
d^3{\rm LIPS} = \frac{dx_B dy d(-\Delta^2)d\phi}{16(2\pi)^4\sqrt{1 + \varepsilon}}
$$

where

$$
q_2 = \ell_+ + \ell_-,\quad x_B = \frac{-q_1^2}{2p_1q_1}, \quad y = \frac{p_1q_1}{p_1k}, \quad \Delta^2 = (p_2 - p_1)^2, \quad \varepsilon = \frac{2x_BM_N}{\sqrt{-q_1^2}},\quad \phi = \mbox{angle between lepton and handron planes in paper's Fig. 2}, \quad \delta_+(r) = \delta(r)\theta(r^0)\ \forall r
$$

$\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

My attempt is to 1st integrate in $k^\prime$ as well as in $p_2^0, q_2^0$ and get rid of the all Dirac deltas up to one. From there I got the formula down below, but I don't know how to go on.

$$
\int d^3{\rm LIPS} = 2\pi \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p_2}}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{\vec{p_2}^{2} + M_N^2}} \frac{d^3 \vec{q_2}}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{\vec{q_2}^{2} + M_{\ell\bar{\ell}}^2}}\delta_+((p_1 - p_2 + k - q_2)^2)
$$

Comment: this is too technical for this site, You could try asking one of the authors of the paper, if you register in arxiv, there is an e-mail of one of them. This site also has mainly theorists and phenomenologists answering https://www.physicsoverflow.org/